# Process sleep when form loses focus

Tags: windows, visual-c++, forms, focus, sleep

While writing a server application with a windows form for a GUI a problem appeared. When a form loses focus the process sleep, so any networking will not work unless the form is in focus the whole time. Is there any way of creating a dialog or window that will keep its process running continuously?

I call a function called cServer::GetInstance()->CheckEvents(); which checks the events of the connection to see if anything special is happening, problem is, this AND the general process of listening on a port halts when the form loses focus. Is there a fix or work around for this?

Comment: "a server application with a windows form for a GUI" - my brain just exploded.  Why does your server app need a GUI?

Comment: Because user friendly interface is a must for this project. Would like to keep it simple with a command line app which you can use flags on to do the setup, but unfortunately I can't for this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a win32 gui app, your networking code should be in an independent dedicated thread.

A better solution over all, would be to make your "server" a windows service and your GUI a client application to the server.